# Can you eliminate cigarette smoke odor between walls?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, smell

If holes are made in dry walls is there a substance that can be sprayed in the walls to eliminate cigarette  odor?

Answer (score 3):

Getting rid of odor is a difficult task in general, particularly since molecules stick to surfaces and often stick *in* surfaces.

There's a good reason that ["Febreze"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Febreze) works well. It contains a [cyclodextrin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclodextrin) ring that binds many odor-causing molecules. So the molecules are still there, but bound in a form you can't smell anymore.

(I remember an anecdote that they had to develop special fragrances to work with Febreze, but I can't find that anywhere.)

I suspect spraying paint primer inside the walls could work. This is often used to fix smoke damage from fires.